# Gallery image with caption. Want border only around image, not caption. Using Divi with custom css

Tags: css, wordpress, border, image-gallery, divi

I am working with Divi and need some custom CSS. I have a gallery wall with image cations under each image. I need to get a border around just the image. I think I might be placing the CSS in the wrong spot in Divi.
I've tried the following code:

```css
        border: 1px solid #707070;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
```

Which works in code pen but not in divi. Ive tried pasting this code in divi>theme options>custom css, in the gallery>advanced>custom css>main element and in gallery item. The image below is the effect I am trying to achieve for each image in the gallery. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you show me your HTML code please, I think those properties should only be indicated to the img element and not to figcaption. Greetings!

Comment: I'm a novice reviewer of answers, but I think your answer would be better posted as a comment to the question.